# react dc.js import not working

Tags: reactjs, dc.js, crossfilter

I am working on react app and using babel as compiler. I need to import dc.js and crossfilter

Added this code
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import dc from 'dc/dc';
    import crossfilter from 'crossfilter/crossfilter';

but getting this error
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _crossfilter2.default) is not a function

Does anyone know of any sample app\example using react and dc.js.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
import crossfilter from 'crossfilter/crossfilter';
```

Do

```
import * as crossfilter from 'crossfilter/crossfilter';
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this but getting error "crossfilter is not a function"  at                          var ndx = crossfilter(data),
          runDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return +d.Run;
      }),

Answer (score 1):

Or:

`var crossfilter = require('crossfilter');`

Or:

`import crossfilter from 'crossfilter';`